# Discord bot won't respond after a perms error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I am making this bot and this certain command requires specific perms to operate.

```
from discord import Member
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions

@bot.command(aliases=["purge"], pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(manage_channels=True, manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=20):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
  await ctx.send(f"{amount} messages, reduced to atoms")

@clear.error
async def clear_error(error,ctx):
  if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        text = ("It seems you don't have the permissions for this, ".format(ctx.message.author))
        await ctx.send_message(ctx.message.channel, text)
```

For some reason, the statement was not met, and no response is given. so I added an else (even tho there shouldn't be)

```
else:
    print("authorised user tried to access but hit an error")
    await ctx.send_message(f"there seems to be an error,{ctx.message.author}")
```

After the print line, it hits an error message, saying there is no attribute called "message" to "MissingPermissions"

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `await ctx.send_message(ctx.message.channel, text)` to-

```
await ctx.send(f"there seems to be an error,{ctx.message.author}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this line:

```
async def clear_error(error,ctx):
```

According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=application%20command%20error#discord.discord.ext.commands.on_command_error), the context argument will come first, and then the error argument. Since you've flipped these, the `error` argument will be the context, and `ctx` will contain the error.

Change the line to this:

```
async def clear_error(ctx,error):
```

After that, change this line:

```
await ctx.send_message(ctx.message.channel, text)
```

To this:

```
await ctx.send(text)
```

The context object will send the text, as it already has information on where the message was sent so it can send a reply.